# Opto-isolated RS232 signal capture

Tags: serial, opto-isolator, rs232

I have a problem in which I need to capture (spy on) an RS232 signal through an opto-isolator. This isolator needs to be high speed since the RS232 signal can reach up to 115200 baud. The main problem is as follows:

Device #1 and #2 talk to each other through a RS232 signal (only Tx and Rx). I would like to capture the Tx signal from device #1 without interfering on their communications:

[image: The Problem]

For safety reasons there needs to be a bit of isolation, so I can't just 'tap' the line and a simple diode would only capture the positive bits of the rs232 signal. I have tried it with a simple diode, but then I get interference on the devices.

I came up with the following; The 6N137 opto isolator (high speed) will take the Tx as input signal. This IC needs 5v Vcc, so I need a L7805 as a voltage regulator to get 5V.  I use a pull-up resistor on the output of the 6N137 so the signal will be 'inverted' (and would actually be TTL Logic). I then take that signal and put it through a MAX232 (which also needs 5v) to get a proper rs232 signal again:

[image]

The things I'm not sure about though, is if the 6N137 would work properly with the RS232 signal. This normally ranges between -9V and 9V right? Can the opto-isolator handle that? Also, do the capacitor and resistor values make sense? Also, if I 'tap' the line, can it be that I draw too much current away from the line, so that Device #2 can't interpreted the signal anymore?

Is there maybe a completely different method which suits way better?

I'm quite novice when it comes to electronics (I'm more of a programmer myself), but very eager to learn. Any help is much appreciated!

**6N137 datasheet:** https://www.tme.com/Document/23c5dd4e02a7db41ce8ad9637e6eba2e/6N137S-L.PDF

Comment: The diode does not isolate, and neither your opto-isolator the way you have connected it, and it requires few milliamps of current to drive the opto. Why not simply send the TX from the device with an Y-cable to the RX of the second device, and also to the RX of MAX232 or another serial port?

Comment: I don't want to directly attach it because I'm afraid that my capturing device would interfere with the signal. Also, if something happens to the capturing device for whatever reason, the signals between device 1 and 2 should still continue without problems. How does circuit not protect the signal? It only flows through the ir-led in the opto-isolator. If the other side 'breaks' it wouldnt matter right?

Comment: The opto will interfere more than another RS232 receiver. Even if the snooping RS232 receiver gets unpowered, it would still work in practice. You could use a MAX232 to receive RS232 and then retransmit RS232 so then the receiver cannot possibly disturb it. Just remove the opto in your diagram and you should be done. I would just connect with a Y cable to snoop with a standard USB RS232 adapter.

Comment: Use a buffer amplifier with a high input impedance, such as an op-amp, before you drive the opto-isolator. Choose an opamp that can handle 24V between supply rails,  connect the opamp output to its inverting input, and feed the RS232 signal to the noninverting input.

Comment: The reverse input voltage of the opto diode is 5V. This means that it cannot be connected to the RS232 Tx signal either directly or via an amplifier. You need at least one more serial diode.
[Here](https://www.broadcom.com/products/optocouplers/industrial-plastic/digital-optocouplers) you can find very small diode current versions and then your system can work as you drew, only with higher R1 resistance and a series diode.

Comment: I would opt to have the RS232 Transeiver connected to the Line and to place the isolation to its digital interface. Yes, now you need to supply the transceiver also with an isolated supply, but this is a clean design and you will get standard iosolater IC's which will do RS232 speed with ease.